# Updating Text Area Swing Java

Tags: java, swing

I have a Swing GUI with a run button with the following code

```
 private void runButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    staticLinkTextArea.append("Building Site Map (this can take a while depending on depth) \n");
    crawl.CrawlerInit("http://www.asquithnurseries.co.uk/", "asquithnurseries.co.uk",1);
    crawl.runCrawler();
    staticLinkTextArea.append("Building Complete Searching for Static Links \n");

    crawl.runListURL();

}
```

I want to let the user know that the site is being crawled and this could take a long time.  However the staticLinkTextArea.append is not taking effect until after crawl.CrawlerInit and crawl.runCrawler complete.  How can I force it to happen first?

Comment: You should call "invalidate()" on staticLinkTextArea to force a redraw. Also consider to put the crawler stuff into an "invokeLater" call. You surely find examples here on stack overflow.

Comment: @AngelO'Sphere: no, `invalidate()` will have no effect here, nor will `repaint()`. The invalidate method only works on Swing layout managers, something not involved here, and again the main underlying problem is the Swing event thread is being tied up. Next your recommendation to use `invokeLater` is even worse and actually dangerous, because then you're guaranteeing that long-running code is being called **on** the EDT which is the exact opposite of what you want to do.

Comment: _"How can I force it to happen first?"_ - Append to the TextArea before running your crawler. _"How can I do this the right way?"_ - @HovercraftFullOfEels beat me to the answer. PS: Damn you Hovercraft! DAMN YOUUUUUUUUU! (JK =P)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to let the user know that the site is being crawled and this could take a long time. However the staticLinkTextArea.append is not taking effect until after crawl.CrawlerInit and crawl.runCrawler complete. How can I force it to happen first?

Yours is a classic example of running long-running code on the Swing event thread, and thereby freezing that thread. The solution is the same as always: run the long-running code in a background thread such as a `new Thread(...)` or a SwingWorker.

e.g.,

```
private void runButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    staticLinkTextArea.append("Building Site Map (this can take a while depending on depth) \n");
    crawl.CrawlerInit("http://www.asquithnurseries.co.uk/", "asquithnurseries.co.uk",1);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            crawl.runCrawler();
            crawl.runListURL();
        }
    }).start();
    staticLinkTextArea.append("Building Complete Searching for Static Links \n");

}
```

Your use of `static` in your method names does worry me, and hopefully they don't mean that you're using static methods here.

Comment: That is fantastic one small thing how to do I make it wait for the thread to end before running

 staticLinkTextArea.append("Building Complete Searching for Static Links \n");

Comment: @PhoenixRising666: that's where using the SwingWorker would help. Google "Concurrency in Swing" and read the first hit. It's a several page tutorial but well worth it. You can wait on the SwingWorker thread either through its `done()` method or through a PropertyChangeListener, your choice.